# can we subclass UIControl and display it in storyboard through our own framework in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Can we  subclass UIControl and display it in storyboard through our own framework in iOS,I knew we can display it through programatically but I want to show in storyboard through subclass.

Answer (score 0):

XCode 6 has a new feature **Live rendering**.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014224-CH41

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have done it and we can do it in custom framework.we just need to follow process as like sub-class for add any UIControl through XIB/Storyboard.